# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Checksum does not match

Tags: tensorflow

when I was trying the pointnet' command `python evaluate.py --visu`. At the beginning, everything went well, but it crushed then.

I am using tensorflow to learn pointnet.

```
https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/evaluate.py
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError
Checksum does not match: stored 3218031918 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 599589009

[[{{node save/RestoreV2}} = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:File "evaluate.py", line 172, in <module>
evaluate(num_votes=1)
File "evaluate.py", line 71, in evaluate
saver = tf.train.Saver()
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1094, in __init__
self.build()
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1106, in build
self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1143, in _build
build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 787, in _build_internal
restore_sequentially, reshape)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 406, in _AddRestoreOps
restore_sequentially)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 854, in bulk_restore
return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 1550, in restore_v2
shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helperop_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3272, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\85395\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1768, in __init__
self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

DataLossError (see above for traceback): Checksum does not match: stored 3218031918 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 599589009
[[{{node save/RestoreV2}} = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT,DT_FLOAT,DT_FLOAT,  DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT],   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save     /Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/evaluate.py)

Comment: I used pycharm's terminal, entered the command about ' python evaluate.py --visu'

Comment: 2019-02-01 11:02:09.982141: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:922] save/Assign_88: (Assign)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
save/Assign_89: (Assign): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0

Comment: this is the beginning's information.

Comment: after few second,it showed this: 2019-02-01 11:02:11.616920: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Data loss: Checksum does no
t match: stored 3218031918 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 599589009